# Касперский vs Delphi XE - Параноики vs разработчики

Tags: delphi, kaspersky

Уже не впервые сталкиваюсь с тем, что АВПО Касперский не даёт нормально что-то разрабатывать.

```
[DCC Fatal Error] F2039 Could not create output file '.\Debug\Win32\Project1.exe'
```

То он удалил все .exe версии приложения "показать пароль под звёздочками" - очень удобно при переносе ОС и восстановления многочисленного ПО, требующего парольный доступ. В Web'е ведь это разрешено.
Теперь же ни как не даёт, внёс уже во все исключения, скомпилировать приложение для работы с реестром, контретнее с функцией  EraseSection - удаление секции\ветки реестра.
Как всё-таки обойти эту паранойю от Касперского?
Или кто как программирует такого рода программы в связки с ПО от Касперского?
P.S. Даже "отключить защиту на 1 час" пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что это будут частные мнения, основанные на личном опыте? у нас, например, помогает внести требуемый exe в исключения. А общая рекомендация нашим клиентам - не пользоваться Касперским (кто бы ей ещё следовал)

Comment: Касперский и другие антивирусы расчитаны на обычных пользователей, которые не пользуются компилятороми и другими "подозрительными программами". Обычные разработчики обычно понимают, что делают и им антивирус на рабочей машине абсолютно не нужен (а иногда даже вреден). Если хочется ходить по левым сайтам - можно завести отдельную машину (виртуальную, например) и там себе исследовать подземный мир.

Comment: @kami, с исключений я и начал, даже саму среду внёс в исключения. Не помогло. Не говоря уже о каталогах, куда компилируется разрабатываемое ПО.

Comment: @KoVadim, мне не по сайтам ходить (для этого есть TOR), мне ПО разрабатывать, не "калькуляторы" и не "блокнотики". А нормальное ПО.
Вывод сделан не в пользу этой конторы, просто они дают бесплатную версию (давали), но обновление БД еще поддерживают. Остальные бесплатные недоантивирусы, устанавливать как-то не хочется.

Comment: TOR - это о другом. Он вряд ли защитит от "плохих сайтов". Я последнее время на виндовых машинах не пользуюсь никакими антивирями (ну кроме стандартного встроенного). На линукс машинах вообще никогда не устанавливал подобного и все нормально.

Comment: "А общая рекомендация нашим клиентам - не пользоваться Касперским (кто бы ей ещё следовал)" - офигенная рекомендация. А заодно отключить все файрволлы, чтобы ваше приложение могло нормально в интернет ходить, ага.

Answer (score 1):

Как показывает моя практика: в 9 из 10 таких ситуаций, срабатывание касперского на скомпилированный экзешник означает наличие где-то в приложении buffer overflow (запись данных за пределы выделенной памяти или по ошибочному адресу "в никуда") - это один из самых распространённых способов использовать различные уязвимости в ОС. И только в 1 случае из 10 - это действительно ложное срабатывание. В последнем случае иногда помогает переупорядочивание кода (смена очерёдности вызова фукнций, где это возможно и/или смена порядка методов у объекта).

Решение с исключениями - не вариант, т.к. у себя-то вы добавите его в исключения, а кто вам разрешит это у пользователей сделать?..

Comment: Возможно вы скопировали код, который кто-то уже использовал ранее и выложил в какой-нить паблик, а потом другой нехороший человек этот код использовал в трояне / вире в результате каспер получил на анализ этот вирь и добавил этот код в свои базы автоматом без участия аналитика. вы включили этот код в свой проект, и не важно, что это не вирус, его кто-то уже мог использовать и теперь вам надо в саппорт каспера обращаться чтобы исправили ложное срабатывание.

Comment: я трижды сталкивался с подобной проблемой? один раз когда только что скомпилированный файл скопированный на машину с антивирем тут же признавался заразой (из-за стороннего кода на паскале). один раз каспер признал вирусом скрипт на PS из аж 3х! операторов в пайпе. get-process | select-object ... | invoke-webrequest, притом что сам файл при проверке не говорил что это вирус, но вот после добавления его в планировщик заданий он его удаляла и ломал планировщик. и один раз каспер неправильно проксировал запросы на фтп через вининет.длл, и долго я себе говлову ломал в чем беда пока его не выключил

Comment: Я обычно не копирую код из интернета.

Comment: еще выруби самозащиту в политиках, если тебе доступно. тогда может прокатит выключение на час. подпись кода тоже помогает. ты проверь еще свою дельфи на вири, может(Если она не лицензионная) она уже содержит вместе с кряком какойнить вирь который добавляет свой код в твое ПО при компиляции и тогда каспер на это триггерит, а основной дистр он не проверяет т.к. ты его добавил в исключения.

Comment: @Yakov, ещё раз: если антивирус реагирует на ваше приложение, то это ваша проблема, а не антивируса. Т.к. у других пользователей будет то же самое, а там никто антивирус отключать не будет. Поэтому нужно решать её другими методами.

Comment: Да что вы такое говорите. антивирус боги пишут. и не ошибаются? Мне лично саппорт признавался несколько лет назад, что каспер неспособен был правильно отследить активное фтп соединение, чтобы файрвол не мешал приложению, и пришлось переделать на пассивное. [https://pastebin.com/8RZwAzVB](Пример моего скрипта) попробуйте сказать, что такого же вирусного в нем было на что может антивирус реагировать. Это был реальный кейс на который ушло 2 недели чтобы заставить поддержку сделать по человечески, а не добавить сервер и порт в исключения, и после смены обратно был сбой

Comment: Еще раз я изложил свой опыт человеку, я лично два раза обращался в службу поддержки Касперсокого (и это только случаи когда он неправильно реагировал на мои приложения, про сторонние я вообще считать не берусь)т.к.*ИХ антивирус работал некорректно*, а не мое приложение, и ОНИ корректировали работу антивируса для моих нужд, т.к. признавали что проблема была в *некорректно работе их ПО*, и не была связана с моим кодом.

Comment: Решение через поддержку антивируса - это и есть один из вариантов правильного решения проблемы. Неправильные - это "добавить в исключения" или "отключить антивирус".

Answer (score 0):

Значит каспер ругается на упаковщик или машинное обучение касперского дает ложно-положительное срабатывание на какой-то код который кто-то писал на дельфи(вирус) и вместо поиска нормальной сигнатуры вируса каспер стриггерил на код библиотечный и теперь все что написано на дельфе попадает под раздачу( у меня так он удалил программу которую делали еще до меня(ей было лет 15 если не больше, а удалил он ее месяцев пару назад, в том числе с хранилки где были бекапы, т.к. мой начальник имел неосторожность подключить ее себе как сетевой диск) и исходников ее не осталось, благо мы ей уже давно не пользуемся, но осадочек остался. от каспера тоже надо защищаться.) открываешь у них кейс и мучаешь пока не поправят, если у тебя лицензионный антивирус то они это обязательно сделают, правда нервы помотают потому что за ними нужно проверять. у меня со скриптом на PS так и было ушло недели две пока нормально сделали.